# How to increase font size of dictionary in lookup?

Tags: mac, font, dictionary

I'm connecting my macbook to a 24inch monitor. When reading in Apple Books, I often use the lookup dictionary. However the font in the popup window is too small for me see. How can I increase it?

For example I'd like to increase the font size of the popup window below:
[image]

Comment: I don't think so. What's the resolution on the monitor?

Comment: @benwiggy 2560x1440. I can change the resolution to make the text bigger but that isn't something I want to do, since it makes everything else bigger too.